# Overlapping rules - mismatched input

Tags: antlr4, lexer

My grammar (as follows (trimmed down from the original)) requires somewhat overlapping rules

```
grammar NOVIANum;

statement :  (priorityStatement | integerStatement)* ;

priorityStatement : T_PRIO TwoDigits ;

integerStatement : T_INTEGER Integer ;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;

T_PRIO : 'PRIO' ;
T_INTEGER : 'INTEGER' ;

Integer: OneToNine Digit*  |  ZERO  ;

TwoDigits : Digit Digit ;

fragment OneToNine : ('1'..'9') ;

fragment Digit: ('0'..'9');

ZERO : [0] ;
```

so "Integer" and "TwoDigits" overlap to a certain extent.

The following input

```
INTEGER 10
PRIO 10
```

results in

```
line 2:5 mismatched input '10' expecting TwoDigits
```

when Integer precedes TwoDigits and in

```
line 1:8 mismatched input '10' expecting Integer
```

when TwoDigits precedes Integer in the grammar.

Is there a way around this ?

Thanks - Alex

**Edit:**

Thanks @GRosenberg, your suggestion, of course, worked for this small example, but when I integrated this into my full grammar it led to different mismatched input errors sure enough.

The reason being another lexer rule which requires a range of '[1-4]', so I thought I'll be clever and turn it into

```
grammar NOVIANum;

statement :  (priorityT | integerT | levelT )* ;

priorityT : T_PRIO twoDigits ;

integerT : T_INTEGER integer ;

levelT : T_LEVEL levelNumber  ;

levelNumber : ( ZERO DIGIT ) | ( OneToFour (ZERO | DIGIT) ) ;

integer: ZERO*  ( DIGIT ( DIGIT | ZERO )* ) ;

twoDigits : (ZERO | DIGIT) ( ZERO | DIGIT ) ;

oneToFour : OneToFour (DIGIT | ZERO) ;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;

T_INTEGER : 'INTEGER' ;
T_LEVEL   : 'LEVEL' ;
T_PRIO    : 'PRIO' ;

DIGIT: OneToFour | FiveToNine ;

ZERO : '0' ;

OneToFour  : [1-4] ;
FiveToNine : [5-9] ;
```

This still works for the previous inputs but ...

```
INTEGER 350
PRIO 10
LEVEL 01
LEVEL 05
LEVEL 10
LEVEL 49
```

results in

```
[@0,0:6='INTEGER',<2>,1:0]
[@1,8:8='3',<5>,1:8]
[@2,9:9='5',<5>,1:9]
[@3,10:10='0',<6>,1:10]
[@4,12:15='PRIO',<4>,2:0]
[@5,17:17='1',<5>,2:5]
[@6,18:18='0',<6>,2:6]
[@7,20:24='LEVEL',<3>,3:0]
[@8,26:26='0',<6>,3:6]
[@9,27:27='1',<5>,3:7]
[@10,29:33='LEVEL',<3>,4:0]
[@11,35:35='0',<6>,4:6]
[@12,36:36='5',<5>,4:7]
[@13,38:42='LEVEL',<3>,5:0]
[@14,44:44='1',<5>,5:6]
[@15,45:45='0',<6>,5:7]
[@16,47:51='LEVEL',<3>,6:0]
[@17,53:53='4',<5>,6:6]
[@18,54:54='9',<5>,6:7]
[@19,55:54='<EOF>',<-1>,6:8]
line 5:6 no viable alternative at input '1'
line 6:6 no viable alternative at input '4'
(statement (integerT INTEGER (integer 3 5 0)) (priorityT PRIO (twoDigits 1 0)) (levelT LEVEL (levelNumber 0 1)) (levelT LEVEL (levelNumber 0 5)) (levelT LEVEL (levelNumber 1 0)) (levelT LEVEL (levelNumber 4 9)))
```

What am I missing here ?

**Edit 2:**

Ok, answering my own question here, of course

```
DIGIT: OneToFour | FiveToNine ;
```

kicks in where it shouldn't, even in this combined form,
so about the only way to get around this - I can think of - would be

```
grammar NOVIANum;

statement :  (priorityT | integerT | levelT )* ;

priorityT : T_PRIO twoDigits ;

integerT : T_INTEGER integer ;

levelT : T_LEVEL levelNumber  ;

levelNumber : ( ZERO (OneToFour | FiveToNine) | ( OneToFour (ZERO | (OneToFour | FiveToNine)) ) ) ;

integer: ZERO*  ( (OneToFour | FiveToNine) ( (OneToFour | FiveToNine) | ZERO )* ) ;

twoDigits : (ZERO | (OneToFour | FiveToNine)) ( ZERO | (OneToFour | FiveToNine) ) ;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;

T_INTEGER : 'INTEGER' ;
T_LEVEL   : 'LEVEL' ;
T_PRIO    : 'PRIO' ;

// DIGIT: OneToFour | FiveToNine;

ZERO : '0' ;

OneToFour  : [1-4] ;
FiveToNine : [5-9] ;
```

because when I create a parser rule for it like

```
oneToNine : OneToFour | FiveToNine ;
```

it'll give me this

```
integerT INTEGER (integer (oneToNine 3) (oneToNine 5) 0))
```

which is ugly and harder to handle than just

```
(integerT INTEGER (integer 3 5 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

As an general issue of design, always try to work with distinguishing elements and their objects (T_PRIO -> TwoDigits) at the same level, parser or lexer.  Presuming the semantic nature of the `Integer` and `TwoDigits` rules is important, promote them to the parser and let the lexer only produce digits.  That is, don't over-constrain the lexer.

In the parser, you can let the `integer` rule *functionally* hide the `twoDigits` rule except in the evaluation of the `priorityStatement` rule:

```
priorityStatement : T_PRIO twoDigits ;

integerStatement : T_INTEGER integer ;

integer: ZERO | ( DIGIT ( DIGIT | ZERO )* ) ;

twoDigits : DIGIT DIGIT ;

T_PRIO : 'PRIO' ;
T_INTEGER : 'INTEGER' ;
DIGIT : [1-9] ;
ZERO : '0' ;
```

Comment: But white spaces are skipped from the lexer, causing input like `"1 2"` *(digit, space, digit)* be potentially matched as a single `integer` by the parser. And `"12"` could be matched as a `twoDigits`.