# antlr4 resolving grammar ambiguities

Tags: antlr4

As a follow up to [Overlapping rules - mismatched input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168411/overlapping-rules-mismatched-input) which helped me to solve ambiguities in interpreting numerics I'm now running into the next issue - numbers are also allowed as part of identifiers, and unfortunately even at the start of an identifier, so ...

This grammar illustrates the problem

```
grammar NOVIANum;

statement :  (priorityT | integerT | levelT )* ;

priorityT : T_PRIO twoDigits ;

integerT : T_INTEGER integer ;

levelT : T_LEVEL levelNumber  ;

levelNumber : ( ZERO (OneToFour | FiveToNine) | ( OneToFour (ZERO | (OneToFour | FiveToNine)) ) ) ;

integer: ZERO*  ( (OneToFour | FiveToNine) ( (OneToFour | FiveToNine) | ZERO )* ) ;

twoDigits : (ZERO | (OneToFour | FiveToNine)) ( ZERO | (OneToFour | FiveToNine) ) ;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;

T_INTEGER : 'INTEGER' ;
T_LEVEL   : 'LEVEL' ;
T_PRIO    : 'PRIO' ;

ZERO : '0' ;

OneToFour  : [1-4] ;
FiveToNine : [5-9] ;

ID : Letter SeparatorAndLetter* ;

Letter : [a-zA-Z0-9];
SeparatorAndLetter : ([\-]* [_]* Letter+);
```

the following input

```
INTEGER 350
PRIO 10
LEVEL 01
```

sure enough results in

```
line 1:8 mismatched input '350' expecting {'0', OneToFour, FiveToNine}
line 2:5 no viable alternative at input '10'
line 3:6 no viable alternative at input '01'
(statement (integerT INTEGER (integer 350)) (priorityT PRIO (twoDigits 10)) (levelT LEVEL (levelNumber 01)))
```

as ID will kick in before integer when parsing "350".

Any way around this ?

Thanks - Alex

Answer (score 2):

Make `ID` a parser rule instead of a lexer rule. If an ID can be just numbers it's not possible for the lexer to seperate it and because your integer lexer rules just match 1 digit the lexer will always favor the `ID` rule for numbers with more than 1 digit (the lexer always tries to match to longest possible input sequence).

The following grammar works for your sample input:

```
grammar NOVIANum;

statement :  (priorityT | integerT | levelT | idT)* ;

priorityT : T_PRIO twoDigits ;
integerT  : T_INTEGER integer ;
levelT    : T_LEVEL levelNumber  ;
idT       : T_ID id ;

levelNumber : LVLNUMBER ;
integer     : LVLNUMBER | TWODIGITS | NONZERONR ;
twoDigits   : LVLNUMBER | TWODIGITS ;

number : LVLNUMBER | TWODIGITS | NONZERONR | ANYNUMBER ;
id     : number | STRING ;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;

T_INTEGER : 'INTEGER' ;
T_LEVEL   : 'LEVEL' ;
T_PRIO    : 'PRIO' ;
T_ID      : 'ID' ;

LVLNUMBER : ZERO (OneToFour | FiveToNine) | OneToFour (ZERO | OneToFour | FiveToNine) ;
TWODIGITS : ZERO ZERO | FiveToNine (ZERO | OneToFour | FiveToNine) ;
NONZERONR : ZERO* (OneToFour | FiveToNine) (ZERO | OneToFour | FiveToNine)* ;
ANYNUMBER : (ZERO | OneToFour | FiveToNine)+ ;

STRING    : (LVLNUMBER | TWODIGITS | NONZERONR | ANYNUMBER | LETTER) (Minus* Underscore* (LVLNUMBER | TWODIGITS | NONZERONR | ANYNUMBER | LETTER)+)* ;

fragment LETTER     : [a-zA-Z];
fragment Minus      : '-' ;
fragment Underscore : '_' ;
fragment ZERO       : '0' ;
fragment OneToFour  : [1-4] ;
fragment FiveToNine : [5-9] ;
```

Although this grammar parses your sample input correctly, it is quite clumsy if you have lots of different special numbers like `LVLNUMBER` or `TWODIGITS`. I would prefer to validate these values (e.g. levelNumber < 50) with a Listener after parsing.

Comment: In this example, the `Number` lexer rule will never match. It needs to be a parser rule `number` instead.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, all bits being at the parser level now then leads to a further issue in that using "id" as in  
  
`T_ID : 'ID' ;`
`idT : T_ID id ;`
  
with an input of  
  
`ID 1Z`
`ID MyLEVEL`
  
results in  
  
`line 9:0 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'`
`(statement (integerT INTEGER (integer 3 5 0)) (priorityT PRIO (twoDigits 1 0)) (levelT LEVEL (levelnumber 0 1)) (idT ID (id (number 1) (separatorAndLetter Z))) (idT ID (id M (separatorAndLetter y))) (levelT LEVEL levelnumber))`

Comment: I.e. everything being a Lexer token will now be identified as such even when it is part of an id (which is now a Parser rule) and thus -> no viable alternative

Comment: Thanks again, @ibizarudi, but no cigar yet, I'm afraid.  
  
An id of LEVELX works ok, but  
  `LEVEL-X` results in `line 10:3 no viable alternative at input 'LEVEL'`  
`line 10:8 mismatched input '-' expecting LvlNumber`  
`(idT ID id) (levelT LEVEL (levelNumber - X)))`

Comment: Updated once again. `STRING` now should match any valid Identifier thats not just numbers only, because these are matched by the four lexer rules directly above. If there happens to be some Identifier that is not matched by `STRING` you should edit this elxer rule to match it to get it to work.